# Finding a commit in GIT which added a specific string

Tags: c#, git

I am looking for a git command which would allow me to find all of the commits where a specific string was added.

The string could also be a regular expression, and I also want to retrieve the specific string in the commit that matches that expression.

Example -

I would like to find all the commits where the pattern - `// FIX - BUG-XXXX` was added to the files. Including matching lines such as: `// FIX - BUG-1234` and
   `// FIX - BUG-2345`
etc.

Comment: I dont think there's any direct git way of doing this. You can create a shell script which does `git log` (get commits) `- > git show` (check what happened in commit) `- >  grep` (check for regex ++.*<your reg ex>)... Somewhere around these lines...

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there isn't a particular way to check through files for a specific string easily.

My guess is you want [git-blame](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame).

For the file that you are wanting to figure out who made the changes, you would run something like:

main.cs

```
$ git blame -L 40,60 main.cs
```

This would search lines 40-60 in `main.cs` for any changes, and report them back to you.